# SilverStripe Check if record is being edited or added?

Tags: silverstripe

I have an extension that extends the `onAfterWrite` method of the parents.

```
<?php
public function onAfterWrite(){
   parent::onAfterWrite();

   $newTask = new Mytask($this->owner->ID);
   $newTask->copyTask();
}
?>
```

**Problem:**

I want to instantiate class  `MyTask` and call its method only when new record is being added, not when the existing record are being edited. How to check whether we just edited existing record or added new record in method `onAfterWrite` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that on the initial write there will be no `ID` set against the object (at least, not during the `onBeforeWrite`).

You can use this to your advantage either by setting a flag on the object (eg: `$this->isFirstWrite = true`) during the `onBeforeWrite` and then checking for it `onAfterWrite`.

UPDATE: As Barry has rightly said, there's a function called `isInDB` that you can use, which just checks if there's an ID - using that may protect you in the future if we no longer explicitly rely on the ID as the indicator of whether it's in the DB.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest `$this->IsInDB()` it returns "True if the object is in the database".  Link to [api](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataObject.html#_isInDB).  This checks if there is an ID, but does so in a nice well named function to make it clear what is going on.

Comment: $this->isInDB() will return true in onAfterWrite as the record is already written to db by then. I have successfully used $this->isChanged('ID') for cases where I need to detect new record but can't do it in onBeforeWrite as I need to add has many relations or something that needs the main record to already be written by then